# Why '' in variable length arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, nameerror

I got an error from this code:

```
def func(**num):
    x = num[a] + num[b] + num[c]
    print(x)
func(a=2, b=3, c=4)
```

The error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(erased)", line 4, in <module>
    func(a=2, b=3, c=4)
  File "(erased)", line 2, in func
    x = num[a] + num[b] + num[c]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Please explain it why `a`, `b`, and `c` in `num[]` requires to be put between `''`?

Comment: **because `a`, `b`, and `c` are not defined anywhere**. Why do you *expect* them to be defined? Are you asking what the difference is between `foo` and `'foo'`? The former is referencing a variable, `foo`, the latter is a string literal. They are two completely different things. This has nothing to do with variable length arguments

Comment: Without quotes, it's interpreting it as a name that's been previously assigned, but you haven't assigned those names within the function. With quotes, it's a string that can be used to do a lookup of a dictionary, among other thing.

Comment: It would be simpler to define your function as `def func(a, b, c): print(a + b + c)`.  Using the `**num` syntax in this situation adds complexity and makes errors more likely.

Comment: Also, think about it like this: your function accepts arbitrary keyword arguments. Lets say Python did auto-assign variables inside the function dependent on what the caller entered as keyword-arguments. What happens if you internally were using a variable `a` for some logic? Python auto-creating an `a` based on user input would cause your `a` to shadow the auto-`a`.

Comment: Study: https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/  (or any other similar tutorial). Note that `**kwargs` is unpacked as a *dictionary*.

Comment: It's not telling you to put `a` et al. in quotes; it's reporting that the literal name `a` is not defined. It's just how the error message is formatted.

Comment: `a` is the name of a variable, `'a'` is a string literal, and the former isn't defined.